# Hooking UITableView to a JSON API

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift, swifty-json

I'm quite new to Swift an I'm trying to hook it up to a UITableView the best possible way. I've decided to use SwiftyJSON, which seem to be simple. My objects in the JSON object could look like following:

```
{
    "id": "146",
    "title": "Esports site Streak provides prize-heavy alternative to traditional betting",
    "url": "http://www.dailydot.com/esports/streak-counter-strike-vulcun-betting/",
    "image_url": "//cdn0.dailydot.com/cache/bb/cc/bbccc49d8271f2f3ed4c40b45c0fe0c0.jpg",
    "date": "2015-04-10 22:07:00",
    "news_text": "test teeeext",
    "referer_img": "1"
}
```

So far i've started by creating a loop which creates loop through all the loops in viewDidLoad

```
for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in jsonArray {

    println(subJson)

}
```

and after that i've created a class for all the news as below:

```
class News {
    var id: Int!
    var title: NSString!
    var link: NSString!
    var imageLink: NSString!
    var summary: NSString!
    var date:NSString!

    init(id: Int, title:NSString, link: NSString, imageLink:NSString, summary: NSString, date:NSString) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.link = link
        self.imageLink = imageLink
        self.summary = summary
        self.date = date
    }
}
```

However I'm not sure whether that is the best approach for creating this? What will my next steps be to hook it up to a UITableView?

Comment: Just make an array of your `News` objects that you create from the json and use that array as the model of your `UITableView`. So the first cell would display the first object of the array, etc.

Comment: could u make a answer with sudo code or a snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea of what to do. You'll need to create an Array first. Then you'll be creating and adding a News object one by one to that array. Then you'll use that array for your tableView's dataSource. In your cellForRowAtIndexPath you'll read in your News objects and display their data.

```
var arrayNews = Array<News>()
self.tableView.dataSource = self

for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in jsonArray {
    // Create an object and parse your JSON one by one to append it to your array
    var newNewsObject = News()
    id:        = //
    title:     = //
    link       = //
    imageLink  = //
    summary    = //
    date       = //
    arrayNews.append(newNewsObject)
}
self.tableView.reloadData() // This will read in your arrayNews array

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsCell") as! NewsCell
    let newsObject = self.arrayNews[indexPath.row] // Assuming this is 1 section

    // set all of your details here
    cell.labelBlahBlah.text = something
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Okay Thank you!! by the way i'm going to loop through 2 json files. one with recent news and one with popular news. Will i need to create to different news classes for this or will i just need to create 2 different arrays and append them to each?

Comment: If they use the same fields then use the same class and create a multi-dimensional array to store the different "sections". Array<Array<News>>. Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath you'll decipher your section by that array. self.arrayNews[section][row].

Comment: cannot assign a value of type array<News> to a value of type uitableviewdatasource

Comment: I am not sure why he is assigning the `dataSource` to the array. Your `UIViewController` should be the `dataSource` because it is the class that will be implementing the `UITableViewDataSource` functions (ie `cellForRowAtIndexPath`). Also make sure you implement `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` (can't remember exact names). You should be setting the number of rows for the tableview to the `count` property of the array.

Comment: That wasn't the point I was trying to make but you're correct. Use the array via delegate methods. The delegate methods access that array. (Didn't intend that on being build-able code)

Comment: Thank you again. How will arrayNews.append(newNewsObject) look if i use  the section Array<Array<News>>